# blogdown::serve_site() throws 'html_dependency not found' error | htmlwidgets threejs

Tags: r, three.js, r-markdown, htmlwidgets, blogdown

While trying to re-build an old *.Rmd* file, with (only) an updated header-info i.e. blog-categories, I'm getting this error:

> Error: path for html_dependency not found: C:/Users/Username/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/threejs/htmlwidgets/lib/threejs-83

The same *.Rmd* file, prior to updating header-info now, generated html-content successfully months ago, with no issues. I think, the updated *blogdown* package isn't able to locate the dependency libraries i.e. [three.js v83](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r83) vs [three.js v85](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r85)

If this is the issue, I'd really appreciate if someone could advise which file I need to update to fix this. Below snapshot shows the error message, and also the Windows file-location of required library.

[image]

Comment: Please show the full example. If you could [minimize it](https://yihui.name/en/2017/09/the-minimal-reprex-paradox/), that will be even better!

Comment: Okay, I figured it's due to cache generated from Rmd chunk option `cache = TRUE`.  After your comment, I tried to reproduce the issue in a different project (with minimal code, and including `library(threejs)` ) and saw it to be working fine. Then I deleted the cache-files for the file causing trouble, and then _html dependency error_ didn't arise. Thank you.

Comment: That is what I suspected, but you didn't provide a full example, and I could not see the actual code chunk from your screenshot.

Comment: Yes, thanks for helping out; your blog on repro-example was informative. Apologies I wasn't comprehensive enough while quoting source-code.

Comment: No need to apologize. As I said, I can understand that you don't know what information is relevant or to provide.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that you cached the code chunk that generated the HTML widget. When caching HTML widgets, you need to be careful about the versions of HTML dependencies. If you cache a widget, basically the next time it will not be created again but directly loaded from the cache database. It will not know any changes outside in the future, such as an update in a certain JS library. When it is loaded from cache, it will still use all paths stored from the last time. In your case, `threejs-83` was changed to `threejs-85`, but your cached widget didn't know it, and was still looking for `threejs-83` (hence the error).

In general, I don't recommend that you cache HTML widgets, due to [the other caching mechanism](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/local-preview.html) in **blogdown**, which should make it fast enough to build a website locally, plus that caching HTML widgets can be tricky.